# JMeter: how to find color attribute of H1?

Tags: jmeter, css-selectors

I am trying to find if the same color is applied on all H1s (heading) on a list of pages.

I am trying the below way of doing it, but it is resulting balnk not even "colorNotFound"

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`<h1>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) can have ["color"](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp) attribute, as far as I recall [`<font>` has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Whatever

The situation you're trying to describe may occur when there is a match but i.e. the element doesn't have the `color` attribute like here:

[image]

So your `getH1` variable will have blank value

And if there is a match and the attribute is there - your variable will have this attribute value:

[image]

Unfortunately we're not telepathic enough in order to help you to fix your [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) query without seeing at least partial HTML response you're trying to validate so in the meantime I can only suggest getting familiarized with [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) guide

Comment: I must have shared the HTML too. Totally missed it. Color is a CSS attribute/property